# Expression for adjusting indicator/cell according to date in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

New to SSRS. I'd like the lines to show up red if they are late from the current date(due 3/16/16, current date 3/31/16) and yellow if they are two days away from being due. [Ideally all of these dates would currently be red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPLpA.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following expression in the background color property of the date cell.

```
=IIF(
Fields!DueDate.Value<Today(),"Red","Yellow" 
)
```

If due date is less than Today date it will color in red the background color of the cell. Otherwise it will color in yellow.

---

**UPDATE:** Three different colors based on the DueDate.

This is the logic flow:

- Due Date < Today. It is due so it will be **Red**
- Due Date - Today <= 2 It will be due in two days, so it will be **Yellow**
- Due Date - Today > 2 It will be due in three days or more, so it will be **Green**

Expression:

```
=Switch(
Fields!DueDate.Value<Today(),"Red",
DateDiff(DateInterval.Day,Today(),Fields!DueDate.Value)<=2,"Yellow",
true,"Green"
)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I'm getting an error saying it's not a valid color? I'm currently in "set expression for: BackgroundColor." I tried with and without a color before and after the expression.

Comment: @d0nut, check the edition a `=` before the whole expression was missing.

Comment: That seems to work! I know I only asked for red or yellow but is it also possible to make it turn green for anything past two days? So if it's after today, it's red. If it's within two days of today, its yellow, and if it's anything beyond two days, its green? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response! I'm getting an error when trying to run this one. I'm adjusting the Fields to the name "DatePromised" in order to reflect my table properly, but I receive a [BC32017] Comma, ')' error

Comment: @d0nut. Oh I had a missing comma in my expression, I've udated it. Try again.

Comment: It's amazing. Thanks so much for the help.